# Return an encoded B64 pdf file

Tags: php

I have a String representing a pdf file encoded in base64.

I can decode the string like this:

```
function get_file_from_b64($b64_file) {
    //Decode pdf content
    $pdf_decoded = base64_decode ($pdf_content);
    //Write data back to pdf file
    $pdf = fopen ('test.pdf','w');
    fwrite ($pdf,$pdf_decoded);
    //close output file
    fclose ($pdf);
    return $pdf;
}
```

I would like to create a page that download the file but I don't want to save the file on the filesystem read it in a php page and then send it back to the browser.

There is a way to send back the file directly without saving it on the filesystem?

For example I can send a file back to the browser like this:

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=downloaded.pdf");
readfile("test/file.pdf");
```

This implies that the decoded file is saved on test/file.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

The readfile command simply echos the content of the file. Instead of doing that echo the variable with your contexts in it.

You will base to base64 decode the PDF if it has been base64 encoded

For example

```
echo base64_decode($pdf_content);
```